# How can I create an HTML page that creates a text file in an apache tomcat server?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, tomcat, soap

How can I create a webpage in HTML that creates a text file in an apache tomcat server (Client side)?

Can you give me an example that works?

I've read a lot about Ajax, JS, and SOAP.js.

Thanks in advance.

P.S.: Please, if this question is too broad or fool, help me to find a way to make it a more appropriate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHP to create Text File if the file specified does not exists, and may I know the reason why you're creating text file in the apache server, is it for logging purposes ?

Comment: I was looking for something like a servlet (well, I already did it, but for the question's sake)